# ADF filter table based on tree selection

Tags: oracle, tree, oracle-adf

How to filter Oracle ADF table contents based on tree selection?

Bindings:

[image: Bindings]

So the table always renders as if the first item would be selected in the tree, but when I click on some other VariablePoint, the table does not change:

[image: Table which does not change when selection changes]

UPDATE

Based on the answers, I was able to configure the following, and it solved the problem:

[image: Configuring Target Data Source]

I made an iterator for every tree level rule and used them as Target Data Source for each tree/tree level rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ADF trees may look somewhat misleading, but they don't actually reflect the data controls (iterators) that your've created in your application module. Trees work on view links accessors. That's why when you select a tree node, iterators don't get any changes.

If you want to see your accessors in your Model project open a view link between any two adjacent view objects used in your hierarchy. In Relationship - Accessors - Destination you will see Accessor Name parameter. Its value would be the name of lower tree level. The same name you will see in your pageDef tree binding in Tree Level Rules section for appropriate level.

So even if you delete all iterators but OrgView1Iterator from your application module data control, your tree would still function (not speaking about table to the right at the moment).

---

Now to make your case work.

1. In your application module data control you will only need this hierarchy:

   - OrgView1
   - VariablePointViewOrgZoneVariable
   - - VariablePointViewOrgZoneVariableVariablePoint

OrgView1 and VariablePointViewOrgZoneVariable are at root level. VariablePointViewOrgZoneVariableVariablePoint is a child of VariablePointViewOrgZoneVariable.
All current children of OrgView1 should be removed from data control.

2. In your page binding in Executables section click green plus and add VariablePointViewOrgZoneVariable iterator (say, VariablePointViewOrgZoneVariable1Iterator).

In your Executables there should be 3 iterators: OrgView1Iterator, VariableDataView1Iterator and VariablePointViewOrgZoneVariable1Iterator.

3. The key part of filtration is Target Data Source attribute. You can find it in your tree binding.
   In your page binding in Bindings section double click on OrgView1. In tree level rules select VariablePointViewOrgZoneVariable tree and disclose Target Data Source at the bottom.
   Click EL Picker, select VariablePointViewOrgZoneVariable1Iterator and OK.

The result should be ${bindings.VariablePointViewOrgZoneVariable1Iterator}.

4. On your page set table's partialTrigger attribute to point to the tree.

After you restart your page filtration should work.

---

I've made a small example showing your case.
Follow instructions and you can run it on your computer or just read through readme. It also applies selection to the last tree level, which you may not need.

https://github.com/ILyaCyclone/adf-tree-to-table-filterandselect

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. So I get it, the problem was with Target Data Source and Iterator configuration. I will update the problem description to include the updated solution.