# ADF tree binding issue

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I'm using 3 levels tree VO's. All three VO's has bind variables. The VO's are connected via View link. I'm using createViewLinkAccessorRS in order to pass the variables from parent to child VO.. i defined Target Data Source (EL_expression) for second and third level.The tree works fine, and the nodes filled correctly (all the way down). The Problem is that the second and the third tree level attributes are only shown in the tree component. anywhere else in the page it looks like they are empty ({bindings.(attname).inputValue} = null) (E.g - after dragging the third tree level "FlowOrder" from the AppModuleDataControl and create a form out of it, and selecting the second node of the tree will update all the third level tree node (please see attached image), but will leave the entire form which was just created empty)

Any idea why the FlowOrder bindings are empty? i assume that maybe it has to do with the bind variable of the VO .. i even  thought i would change the tree selection listener so on the second level click it will perform a full query of "FlowOrder" via executewithparams, but it does not make any sense  because the  data was fetched already after clicking level 2 tree)
(Jdeveloper : 12.2.1.2.0)

attached image: [Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x470C.png)

Comment: Please include your image in the post.

Comment: it does not let me... i added the image as external https://i.stack.imgur.com/x470C.png

Answer (score 0):

Check out my explanation on trees and example application in another post: [ADF filter table based on tree selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45495542/adf-filter-table-based-on-tree-selection/45504179#45504179) The tree shows data from view link accessors. The form shows data from view instance. They are in different state.